# missing some data after data is sent by FS1000A / XY-MK-5V 433Mhz TX/RX Module (WIFI)

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi

I miss some data ( mostly, the latest characters of one data) when I want to send several messages from arduino to another arduino. 
I'm trying to send and receive some data from arduino to another arduino and I'm using arduino UNO and FS1000A / XY-MK-5V 433Mhz TX/RX Modules. If I only want to sent `Hello there` It works very well but if I want to send several things I miss something. for example for this code, it works very well :
Transmitter:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
// Initialize the IO and ISR
vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{
  char msg[11]="Hello there";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 11);
  vw_wait_tx();
  delay(1000);
}
```

receiver:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
// Initialize the IO and ISR
vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{
  char msg[11]="Hello there";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 11);
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
delay(1000);
}
```

the result is :

`Device is ready
Received: Hello there
Received: Hello there
Received: Hello there
Received: Hello there
Received: Hello there
Received: Hello there`

for this code I missed some data: 
transmitter:

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>
void setup()
{
// Initialize the IO and ISR
vw_setup(2000); // Bits per sec
}
void loop()
{

char msg[11]="Hello there";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 11);
  vw_wait_tx();
  char msg2[7]="Goodbye";
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg2, 7);
  vw_wait_tx();
delay(1000);
}
```

The result is :

`Device is ready
Received: Hello there
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t
Received: Goodbye
Received: Hello t`

Comment: Your array is too short. "Hello there" is char[12] because of the implicit null terminator. so you are corrupting your program. same applies for goodbye. also the receiver code is identical to the transmitter code.

Comment: Also,  the delay(1000) in the loop() of the receiver could cause the receiver to be in a wait state while the transmitter is sending something.

Comment: Thank you,I did both of these, but it doesn't work